# LVM boot activation sequence

Tags: linux, systemd, lvm

I should write a SystemD service to execute a fsck on some LVM volumes.

In order to set the right dependencies I have analyzed the boot sequence by the command **systemd-analyze plot**.

Unfortunately my systemd service does not find any device inside /dev/mapper, whatever before/after constraints I define for it, and so I cannot run the filesystem check. Obviously all the LVM volumes are available at the end of the boot sequence.

Could anybody point me on how to discover which is the right LVM service to add to the **after** contraints to get volumes available for filesystem checking?

Comment: I think, there is no reason to write SystemD service for this. SystemD boot sequence successful read partitions info from /etc/fstab during the boot process and translate it in SystemD units itself. In /etc/fstab sixth field intended to fsck properties. [man 5 fstab](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/fstab.5.html). I hope it's will solve your task.